# Why doesn't '%matplotlib inline' work in python script?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following does not work:

[image]

However this totally works in Jupiter Notebook.

[image]

If I simply comment it out, the graph doesn't show up. (Maybe it won't show up anyways)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

from numpy.random import randn
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data/playgolf.csv', delimiter='|' )
print(df.head())

hs = df.hist(['Temperature','Humidity'], bins=5)
print(hs)
```

Comment: % being used like that isn't valid Python syntax. This must be an operator unique to Jupiter, because normally `%` represents the modulo; that is, the remainder when one number is divided by another.

Comment: Jupiter Notebook has features that aren't part of the Python language itself. All the %-prefixed commands are special extensions, not regular Python statements.

Comment: @Blckknght would you recommend and alternatives?

Comment: You should be able to simply leave the `%matplotlib inline` part out. That only has meaning within Jupiter Notebook: it makes matplotlib's plots appear within the notebook cells instead of as separate windows. Since you don't have a notebook window for them to be embedded in, the separate windows are the only way to go.

Comment: @ZHU You can add `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'` in `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` so you won't bother with `%matplotlib inline` anymore :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Other answers and comments have sufficiently detailed why `%matplotlib inline` cannot work in python scripts.

To solve the actual problem, which is to show the plot in a script, the answer is to use

```
plt.show()
```

at the end of the script.

Comment: however this works in showing the plot in a matplotlib window, but doesn't automatically display the plot in a notebook if the script is called from the notebbok itself and the backend is not `inline`. HuynhTan's answer works in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using notebook and run my_file.py file as a module

Change the line "%matplotlib inline" to "get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')".
Then run my_file.py using this %run
It should look like this:

In my_file.py:

> get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

In notebook:

> %run my_file.py

This run my_file.py in ipython, which help avoid the bug

> NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

According to http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html, `%` is a special iPython/Jupyter command:

> Define an alias for a system command.
>
> `%alias alias_name cmd` defines `alias_name` as an alias for `cmd`

In standard Python, `%` takes the remainder when one number is divided by another (or can be used for string interpolation), so in a standard Python program, `%matplotlib inline` doesn't make any sense. It does, however, work in iPython, as described above.